# How would I group remaining ungrouped arguments?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Trying to make a kick message appear with a reason that you say in the kick command. How would I group the rest of the argument after the mention? I need to have it grouped after the mention because some people have spaces in their names that throw of the argument order.

```
args.slice(prefix, message.mentions.users.first());
                let reasonKick = args.join(' ');
```

Comment: Could you take a user mention as the person to kick and avoid the issue of names with spaces entirely?

Comment: why are you slicing with a user object?

Comment: @fasteroid, that's what I already use to find the member to kick. I just want to know how to separate the kick command and message so I can display a reason.

Comment: @Elitezen, correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're asking why I'm using a user block instead of a regular args[0, 1] command but if I do that and the person I'm kicking has a space in their username, part of their username appears in the kick reason.

Comment: I understand your approach, but `Array.slice()` takes indexes as arguments. `message.mentions.users.first()` returns an entire Discord User Object not an array's index. You have to access the `.username` property and *then* access the length of the string. `...first().username.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your command is structured `!command [user] [reason]`, just use the rest operator (also known as spread)

```js
let [cmd, user, ...reasonKick] = args;
```

Documentation on [The Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: It's structured `prefix command userMention reason`

Comment: Then just add a variable definition to the array of destructured values accordingly

Comment: ie `[prefix, cmd, user, ...kickReason]`

Comment: How would I define `reasonKick`? My original idea was to define it as anything else after the command and mention.

Comment: That's already done with the rest operator. `reasonKick` is assigned the *rest* of the arguments. Hence why it's called the rest operator